# symfony2 - debugbar missing database doctrine info

Tags: php, debugging, symfony

When I log in to my app the db request bar dissapears?  How do I make it show that it always.
shows?

The screenshot at the top shows the database doctrine count, the one at the bottom doesn't.  It dissapears after a successful login

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not a simple display problem? (can you still see it in the HTML code?)

Comment: when I delete one of the items using firebug console it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by making the text smaller.  Adding the following css did the trick

```
.sf-toolbarreset span, .sf-toolbarreset div {
  font-size: 9px !important;
}
```